# Translation needed for painting scrolls

Tags: translation

[image]

I have several scroll paintings and have no idea who the artist is or what they are titled.
not even sure what the exact language is on the scrolls.
Please help to translate the writing in the photo or atlas point me in a direction to where I may find a credible answer.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is traditional Chinese

1. 絹本麒麟送子中堂
2. 絹本六子戲彿中堂

   - 絹本 means "silk cloth".  *It describes the material of the scroll*
   - 《麒麟送子》 (Qilin Delivers Baby) is the title of scroll 1
   - 《六子戲彿》 (Six Children Playing With Buddha) is the title of scroll 2
   - 中堂 is a hanging shaft hung on the central wall of a room. *It describes the function of the scroll*